# Connection to Azure AD Host is succesfull but when prompted to a Log in screen Azure AD Credentials Don't Work

Tags: remote-desktop, azure, credentials, azure-activedirectory

I'm having trouble logging into AzureAD joined machine once I have made a successful RDP Connection. I can see the desktop and login screen but my login doesn't work and I have confirmed those login details work by using a different remote connection service to connect and the credentials work when I input them there.

Background Information the company has a hybrid azure ad setup. Connecting with RDP requires a connection to the RD Gateway server to be made which requires login with AD credentials not Azure.When Authenticated it brings me to the computers log in screen is where I have the problems

Logging in with Azure Credentials to the RD Gateway does not work. NLA on the computer has been disabled. Local Account Works to log in no suprise

My Assumption is something is wrong with the computer as the RDP file I use works for other users. But more testing is going to happen and I will update this question